# Multiple Datatables' and only one table header adjusts

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have multiple datatables and due to them being configured upon the dom loading, the headers are misaligned. I've used the:

```
    $('.myclass').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
       $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
       .columns.adjust()
       .fixedColumns().relayout();
     })
```

This slightly worked, only the final table of four was adjusted. I would like all of the tables to adjust when shown. Is there another solution or am I missing something?

Example linked below

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/231606/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why try to convert `$.fn.dataTable.tables` to a jQuery instance? But look at the [**docs**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.tables()) and do this instead:

```js
$('div.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var tables = $.fn.dataTable.tables({ api: true });
  tables.columns.adjust().draw();
  tables.fixedColumns().relayout().draw();
});
```

You can `visible: true` to the params if you just want to target the modal that is about to be shown.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still is not functioning as it should. I tried both with and without the visible parameter and it didn't trigger a single adjustment.

Comment: @JCode, you had two major problems in the fiddle **1**) You had not included FixedColumns **2**) You had used the same `id` for all tables. The last thing caused DataTables logic to fail. Use different unique `id`'s or use no `id`'s at all. Forked fiddle that is working -> **https://jsfiddle.net/Lgbkf236/**

Comment: Thanks. I'm inexperienced with jquery. It's working.